# Is the noun "Trigger" a trigger-word to avoid?

Tags: usability, copywriting, content

In the document model for a rich messaging experience, my internal model is a hierarchy of Scenes and Nodes on them, with attached *Triggers* that invoke *Actions*.

I'm exposing that hierarchy in a tree-like editor.

It occurred to me that using the word *Trigger* out there in the hierarchy may bother some people.

For now, I'm trying *Senses* as an alternative.

So instead of a noun-oriented Trigger: Touch, Trigger: Property Change I now have Senses Touch, Senses Property Change.

I couldn't find general advice on sensitive words, are there any word lists I can review in the same way you would review accessibility guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the word "trigger" should be avoided.**

It's a totally loaded word now. Like the word snowflake, it has a new primary meaning to a major portion of users. A meaning very different and very profound tied to politics, sexism, racism, etc.

Once people adopt a word like this in this way, it makes no sense to use the word unless you're fighting its abuse.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say no, there's not a catch-all, universal list of 'words to avoid'. A lot really depends on context. One person's trigger is another's completely serviceable, innocuous verb.

If you're gut's telling you not to use a term, then use a different one. There are plenty of synonyms for 'trigger'.

Comment: Completely agree with the "gut" comment. We should all pay more attention to that as its frequently a byproduct of user empathy!

Comment: "Gut" is also inextricably linked to our bias and prejudices. That doesn't mean we should not use intuition, but we should always try to verify our assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

There can't be a list of words to ban in all circumstances. General context changes the meaning of a word, sensitivity depends on your audience, etc.

Ideally, you should test the functionality with different words with a number of potential user to see which word is the easiest to understand and the least problematic.